# Inserting string array value in for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays

I know this is a very simple thing, but I can't see any examples of doing this with strings.  This is beyond the basic exercise in my self imposed homework, and more advanced, but I know it can be done so I just want to go ahead and learn these arrays :-D

I'm trying to change the value if the string in the GLabel below:

```
private void printSubclassBoxes(){
        String[] anArray = {"GraphicsProgram", "ConsoleProgram", "DialogProgram"};

        int  coordinateX = ((getWidth() - BOX_WIDTH) /4);
        int otherCoordinateX = coordinateX;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){

            double coordinateY = (getHeight() / 2);     
            GRect classBox = new GRect (coordinateX, coordinateY, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);

            GLabel classLabel = new GLabel ("ARRAY WILL GO HERE");
            double labelCoordinateX = (coordinateX + ((classBox.getWidth() / 2) - (classLabel.getWidth() / 2)));
            double labelCoordinateY = (coordinateY + ((classBox.getHeight() / 2) + (classLabel.getAscent() / 2)));
            add(classBox);
            add(classLabel, labelCoordinateX, labelCoordinateY);
            coordinateX = otherCoordinateX + coordinateX;

        }   

    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can u pls explain what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but do you mean something like `GLabel classLabel = new GLabel(anArray[i]);` ?

Comment: That was exactly it spong-I knew it was a total noob thing, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
GLabel classLabel = new GLabel (anArray[i]);
```